# Fetch vote count on sites other than Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, vote-count

If I'm not mistaken, SO is the only site that lets you click on the vote total and view the separate up/down score. It makes a **huge** difference whether an answer is +51/-1, or +86/-36.

I'd love to have this feature on other sites. Is there a reason it's disabled/not implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have 1,000 reputation points on a given site to use this feature.  It should be available on all the sites, though.

Comment: Confirmed. The split vote counts have been implemented on *every* site, provided you have the necessary rep.

Comment: That's an odd requirement. Oh well, now I know. Also, the code @Simon posted unfortunately no longer works. (Tested in FF, Opera)